# Não consigo acessar banco pelo SQL server - DSN

Tags: php, sql-server

Tenho uma classe que consigo me conectar ao MySql, e gostaria de usa-la pra acessar um banco de dados numa rede local e que está no SQL SERVER 2014.

```
private static function Conectar() {
    try {
        if (self::$Connect == null):
            $dsn = 'sqlsrv:host=' . self::$Host . ';database=' . self::$Dbsa;
            //$options = [ PDO:: PGSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'];
            self::$Connect = new PDO($dsn, self::$User, self::$Pass); //, $options);
            self::$Connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        endif;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        PHPErro($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
        die;
    }

    return self::$Connect;
}
```

Mas não consigo me conectar porque dá o erro de `could not find driver`. Já baixei a versão `SQLSRV32`, joguei pra pasta *C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16\ext (usando wampserver64)*, num notebobok com windows 10 64. Mesmo editando o arquivo `php.ini` e habilitando as .dll's :

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts 
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts 
php_sqlsrv_56_ts 
php_sqlsrv_56_nts.
```

Mesmo com tudo isso, não consegui me conectar. Como faço para conseguir isso?

Comment: Crie um arquivo de teste com esse conteúdo `<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);ini_set('display_errors', true);error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);` veja se aparece algum erro. Qualque alteração no php.ini não esqueça de reiniciar o apache.

phpinfo();`